# how to use project site (risk or issue) as a list template

Tags: site, template

i was trying and spent some time on save Project site risks as a list template and then reuse it in another project site as a way of importing and exporting the list among sites instead of copying the list content manually which is time consuming.

basically i have tried to save risks list as a template and i have found it there in lists templates but unfortunately when going to site content > add an APP , the list template is not there.

while the above steps worked when using normal SharePoint list, where i can find my normal SharePoint list template

any ideas ?